# How to make a macro file recognize TABs of first macro file js variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, tabs, imacros

I am a beginner, trying to pass a imacros variable into JavaScript, but it failed. I run FF 55.0.3 on Win 7 32 bit, imacros ver. v8.9.7

I have 2 iim scripts that I call from JS, the first one runs only once.

The first one do some tasks on 2 URLs on 2 TABS, back and forth, when it finishes its task, js call the the second iim file, the second iim file should work on those opened 2 TABs as well,

But second macro script does not remember the TAB 1, to go back and do some work.

When first macro finishes its task, ends on TAB T=1, so the second macro starts to work on TAB 1, and it goes to TAB 2 even though TAB 2 was first opened from first macro file.

But when it should go back to TAB 1, it won't, so the first macro file do not carry tabs memory to second macro, and I have no idea how to do so.

(no new TAB on second macro file).

I have tried this in the second macro file:

```
SET MyTB 1
TAB T={{MyTB}}
```

and in JS file

```
 iimPlay("MyMacro-1");
var retcode;
retcode = iimPlay("MyMacro-1")

SET !MyTB
PROMPT {{!MyTB}}

if (retcode > 0) {
retcode = iimPlay("MyMacro-2")
}
iimDisplay (retcode);
for (var i=0;i<=9;i++) {
iimPlay("MyMacro-2");
}
```

but I get error on line with this code: `SET !MyTB`.

I am not sure this is the right approach in JS to make it work, but I have to try it.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I made it work, it was not needed to have it on js file,
I had have the variable in macrofile 2, now it is working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you figured it out, you can mark your own answer as accepted, so the question does not appear as unanswered to others. You might also consider elaborating a bit more on the solution in your answer so that others who might be facing a similar situation know what to do.